# Sealing templates in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Are there any known guidelines or best practices about calling Seal() on templates created from background code in WPF?
I'm trying to improve performance of a WPF app.

Digging around in the reference source from [FrameworkTemplate.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/FrameworkTemplate.cs) 
I guess that the two most important things sealing does are:

- Cleans up temporary variables used during Xaml parsing (good)
- Calls DetachFromDispatcher() on the template (I don't understand the performance implications of this)

So my guess is that I should call Seal() on templates read from Xaml because that frees up some memory, and (even if it's just for consistency) I should also call it on the DataTemplates created with FrameworkElementFactory, although it probably does not do anything noticeable there.

Comment: +1 good question, might also look at [freezables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509(v=vs.110).aspx)